# file system with errors

Tags: server, system-installation, filesystem, sd-card, fsck

I am trying to run Ubuntu on a SBC (single board computer),so that it consumes minimal resources while still having a GUI to work with. The board vendor provides a Ubuntu 16.04 Server image that I successully burnt onto a micro SD card.

The SD card is tested and recommended by the vendor for installing Ubuntu image. Now when I boot from the SD card, everything loads but sometimes I get an error message flooding the terminal saying:

`end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0,sector some_value_here`

`Buffer I/O error on device mmcblkop2, logical block some_value_here`

`Aborting journal on device mmcblk0p2-0`
`EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): Remounting filesystem read-only`

and the files go into read only mode as the error says.On rebooting the following is displayed:

```
Begin: Checking root file system ... fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
rootfs: recovering journal
rootfs: contains a file system with errors, check forced
rootfs: Deleted inode 4805 has zero dtime. FIXED
rootfs: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found


rootfs: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
fsk exited with status code 4
done
Failure: File system check of root filesystem failed
The root filesystem on /dev/mmcblk0p2 requires a manual fsck
```

I have tried to remount the device with rw permissions but since the file system turns to read only type, it does not work. I am stuck at this point. Would appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: Sounds like the SD card is bad, or failed to build properly.

Comment: Could be caused by sudden card removal or poweroff. Don't do that. Read `man shutdown`.  If you can reboot to single-user mode (hold Shift while rebooting to get a menu). Read http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/fsck.8.html or `man fsck` First!

Comment: running fsck on the card did find errors and it deleted some portions. But what really solved was a brand new SD card similar to the one recommended by vendor. Thanks for your input guys. :)